# FLASH CS6 AS3 Sound from libary not on call

Tags: flash, audio

can anyone see where is is not working please ?

i am trying to get a sound from the imported libary to play on button click,

```
button_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToPlayStopSound_2);

var fl_SC_2:SoundChannel;


var fl_ToPlay_2:Boolean = true;

function fl_ClickToPlayStopSound_2(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(fl_ToPlay_2)
    {
        var s:Sound = new Sound(new ("dog.mp3"));
        fl_SC_2 = s.play();
    }
    else
    {
        fl_SC_2.stop();
    }
    fl_ToPlay_2 = !fl_ToPlay_2;
}
```

**I receive this error,**

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 21  1120: Access of undefined property dog.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that is how you're supposed to play a sound from the library...

`var s:Sound = new Sound(new ("dog.mp3"));` isn't correct.

You need to set linkage class name of the sound in the library, then create the object (and can cast into a `Sound` object), then you can play it.

Example: when I have set my linkage class name to `DogSound`, I can then go:

```
var sound:Sound = new DogSound();
```

Comment: Class name = Dog
Base Class = flash.media.Sound
export for ActionScrips x
Export in Frame 1 x

'code' 


button_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToPlayStopSound_2);

var fl_SC_2:SoundChannel;


var fl_ToPlay_2:Boolean = true;

function fl_ClickToPlayStopSound_2(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
 if(fl_ToPlay_2)
 {
  var s:Sound = new DogSound();
  fl_SC_2 = s.play();
 }
 else
 {
  fl_SC_2.stop();
 }
 fl_ToPlay_2 = !fl_ToPlay_2;
}
'code'
ERROR message now reads 'code'Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 14 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method DogSound.
 'code' thanks for helping.

Comment: "DogSound" is just an example. It looks like you've used the class name "Dog" instead, so use "Dog"?

Comment: *** `code` 

button_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToPlayStopSound_2);

var fl_SC_2:SoundChannel;


var fl_ToPlay_2:Boolean = true;

function fl_ClickToPlayStopSound_2(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
 if(fl_ToPlay_2)
 {
  var s:Sound = new Dog();
  fl_SC_2 = s.play();
 }
 else
 {
  fl_SC_2.stop();
 }
 fl_ToPlay_2 = !fl_ToPlay_2;
}
 `code`*** THIS WORKS THANKS mitim n 
Bhavik Ambani

Comment: now the dog barks and stops on the push of a button,
 if I change the name of the dog.mp3 to say 1.mp3 in the library and cat.mp3 to 2.mp3  i would need to change `code` var s:Sound = new Dog(); `code` to `code` var s:Sound = new 1();`code` to play dog.mp3 and 2 to play cat.mp3 , where do i start to code it to become either a cat or dog randomly, would i change 1() into a function to pick a random number like `code`function (catordog) return integer = catordog.mp3: as sound  `code`

Comment: I don't think you can name classes with numbers like that. Maybe just keep it as "Dog" or "Cat", then write a method/function that will return "Dog" or "Cat" randomly.

Comment: if it can return and play the file names dog.mp3 or cat.mp3 then it must there be possible to return and play 1.mp3 or 2.mp3 / this would then mean, it is easier to scale up to play 101.mp3 just by making the ramdon factor 1 to 101. thus being able to add new animales to the ark. ,,, its trying to work out how and where to code in the random lines i am trying to work out now. any pointers ? thanks mitim.

Comment: Your mp3's filename can be named with whatever you want, but I'm pretty sure that I don't think you can name classes starting with numbers. Trying to do something like "new 1()" or "1()" should give you errors...though go ahead and try it and see. In the long run having all your names as 1...101 may make maintainability confusing too. Say the sound for giraffe isn't working or you want to update the mp3 file. You wouldn't easily be able to tell which file/number it is without having a list in another place.

Comment: If you want the ability to play random sounds as well as being able to load 'n' sound files, I'd suggest storing your loaded sound objects into an array. Either that or create a lookup table to map numbers to sounds. Looking at your original code, you may have to restructure it a bit and have it create all the sound objects first instead.

Comment: '
so like
10 - load sound {point to sound file load all}
20 - on event pick random from {1 to arraey}
30 - Play sound new.random.mp3